# Round robin scheduler using a linked list

Tags: java, scheduling, round-robin

I'm trying to write a very simple OS simulator and I am stuck getting my round robin algorithm to work. Basically what i am trying to do is create a circular linked list that stores the burst values of the process. Right now I am getting a null pointer exception. It has been awhile since I've used a linked list so bear with my code:

```
public static void RR3(int numProcess, int[] cpuBurst, int[] arrivalTime){
    int quantum = 3,time = 0, temp;
    int completionTime = 0;
    LinkedList <Integer>process = new LinkedList();
    for (int i = 0; i < numProcess; i++) {
        process.add(i, cpuBurst[i]);
    }

    while (process.isEmpty() != true){

        for (int j  = 0; j < quantum; j++) {
            System.out.println(process.getFirst());
            if(process.peek() == 0 ){
                completionTime = completionTime + time;
                process.remove();
            }
            else{
                temp = process.pop();
                process.push(temp - 1);                   
                time++;                  
            }
        }
        process.addLast(process.getFirst()); 
        process.removeFirst();
    }

    double act = (double) completionTime/numProcess;
    System.out.println("-----------------RR3-----------------");
    System.out.println("             Act = " + act + "ms");  
}
```

Am I using linked list right? Any help is appreciated. 
edit:
I put in System.out.println(process.getFirst()); after the first for loop to get some sort of stack trace and this is my output:

> 6
>   5
>   4
>   4
>   3
>   2
>   10
>   9
>   8
>   7
>   6
>   5
>   3
>   2
>   1
>   7
>   6
>   5
>   Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
>   4
>   3
>   2
>   1
>   4
>   3
>   1
>       at java.util.LinkedList.getFirst(LinkedList.java:242)
>   2
>   1
>       at OsSimulator.RR3(OsSimulator.java:61)
>       at OsSimulator.main(OsSimulator.java:79)
>   Java Result: 1

my burst time i entered were 6,4,10,7 so it looks like it is on the right track but i get the error with this line

```
process.addLast(process.getFirst());
```

and now its a no such element exception.

Comment: Can you show the parameters you passed in the method call.?

Answer (score 0):

It means what it says.  There is no first element, so the `process` list is empty.

This must be occurring because processing the quanta in the `j` loop has made the list empty.

If you add trace code to print out the whole list during each iteration rather than just the first element, it will become pretty obvious what's happening.

Debugging is always about making yourself see what is really going on instead of guessing at an opaque puzzle.  The main tool you have to visualize what's really going on (when your brain fails you) is the machine itself.   Add trace code or become expert with a debugger.  The discipline is to force yourself to see truth.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to eclipse to check this at the moment, but are you sure you aren't trying to call `process.getFirst()` after the last element is removed from the list inside of the for loop?

I would suggest putting a breakpoint before that line and then running the code in debug mode to verify.

Answer (score 0):

Before calling `process.getFirst()` make sure `List` is not empty

```java
public static void RR3(int numProcess, int[] cpuBurst, int[] arrivalTime) {
    int quantum = 3, time = 0, temp;
    int completionTime = 0;
    LinkedList<Integer> process = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numProcess; i++) {
        process.add(i, cpuBurst[i]);
    }

    while (process.isEmpty() != true) {
        for (int j = 0; j < quantum; j++) {
            if (process.size() == 0)
                break;

            System.out.println("Process: " + process.getFirst());
            if (process.peek() == 0) {
                completionTime = completionTime + time;
                process.remove();
            } else {
                temp = process.pop();
                process.push(temp - 1);
                time++;
            }
        }
        if (process.size() == 0)
            break;
        process.addLast(process.getFirst());
        process.removeFirst();
    }

    double act = (double) completionTime / numProcess;
    System.out.println("-----------------RR3-----------------");
    System.out.println("             Act = " + act + "ms");
}
```